# Unable to import JIRA in Python

Tags: python, jira

I am trying to use the JIRA API for Python:
`from jira import JIRA`
`import jira.client`

however, I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\a5102354\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jira\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from jira.client import JIRA  # noqa: E402
                       
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'doc'
```